# Insert an Org Unit with Google Apps Script getting Bad Request error

Tags: google-apps-script, google-admin-sdk, organizational-unit

I have followed the API documentation to insert an org unit but I am recieving a "Bad Request" error. Here is a snippet of my code.

```
function orgUnitCreate() {
  var resource = {
    name: first+' '+init,
    parentOrgUnitPath: '/Students/'+unit,
    blockInheritance: false
  };
  
  AdminDirectory.Orgunits.insert(resource, "myCustomerID redacted for privacy");//This is the line throwing the error
}
```

Thank you for your help

edit: I did indeed have an error in my customer ID, thank you

Comment: Your snippet worked fine for me, but I could reproduce the "Bad Request" by giving it an invalid customer ID, so you might want to check whether you're using the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

### This error can result from

- A required field or parameter hasn't been provided.
- The value supplied or a combination of provided fields is invalid.

`400 Bad Request response status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error`

### Summary

As mentioned in the comment section, this problem might be caused by a missing/incorrect customerID.

### Reference

- [400 Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400)

Answer (score 0):

```
function orgUnitCreate() {
   var resource = {
       name: first+' '+init,
       parentOrgUnitPath: '/Students/'+unit,
       blockInheritance: false
   };
   try {
      resp= AdminDirectory.Orgunits.insert(resource, "my_customer"); 
   } catch (e) {
      resp = e; //Catch The error
   }
   Logger.log(resp);
}
```